# Reliable lengths for a Javascript object array literal?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

There are lots of questions like this but...duh...I can't get it to work.  How do I...take an object literal like this:

```
locations = {};

locations.activities = [
{ text:'biking'},
{ text:'hiking'},
{ text:'boating'},
{ text:'studying'},
{ text:'reading'},
];
```

And print out the activities array values?

IE and Firefox are  getting different lengths (6 and 5 respectively).

Thanks

Comment: How are you printing them out?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "print out"

Comment: IE and Firefox are getting different values due to your trailing comma after the last item. Firefox is ignoring the null value while IE seems to care about it. using `console.log` should give you some indication. Otherwise, use a for loop and log or put each value on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the trailing comma: remove it for cross-browser compatibility reasons.

The inconsistent behavior is caused because *some browsers parse the literal incorrectly<sup>1</sup> when a trailing comma is present*. The correct behavior is to [ignore the trailing comma](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4)<sup>2</sup>:

> If an element is elided at the end of an array (i.e. [...,]), that element does not contribute to the length of the Array.

---

<sup>1</sup> The syntax works *correctly* in IE10 but *incorrectly* in IE9 and before. This can be verified by testing `[1,].length` from the console in the relevant browser mode. The values reported are 1 (correct) and 2 (incorrect), respectively.

<sup>2</sup> The trailing comma is relevant in the case of `[,]` which should be equivalent to `[undefined]`.

Comment: oh, thank you so much!  My sanity thanks you.  Darn those trailing commas.  I'll never use them again (I'm compulsive like that).  There always a reason...it is nice to know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify(locations.activities);`

Comment: yes I think you are right, JSON is the way to go. That would save me all the looping I have to do.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
locations = {};
locations.activities = [
{ text:'biking'},
{ text:'hiking'},
{ text:'boating'},
{ text:'studying'},
{ text:'reading'},
];


 $.each(locations.activities, function(){
  alert(this.text);
 });
```

js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mhnHx/

Comment: thanks Raghu, the only hesitation I have about using $each on JavaScript object is the order is not guaranteed?  If I end up adding a sequence property then I'll use each.